# What does INTERVAL '182' DAY(3) mean in SQL / Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

Trying to understand INTERVAL and DAY(3) usage in SQL, as I've come across it and need to understand what it means. It's in a WHERE clause, seen below

`WHERE POSTING_DATE > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '182' DAY(3)`

Help needed, thanks!

Comment: You appear to be trying to find the rows where the posting date is more than 182 days before the current date. 182 days is half (rounded down) of 365 days, or half a year, so if you are looking for values 6 months before today then you may be better to use `WHERE POSTING_DATE > ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -6)` as that will handle leap years and may be easier to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-B03DD036-66F8-4BD3-AF26-6D4433EBEC1C):

> `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` stores a period of time in terms of days, hours, minutes, and seconds. This data type is useful for representing the precise difference between two datetime values.
>
> Specify this data type as follows:
>
> `INTERVAL DAY [(day_precision)]`
>    `TO SECOND [(fractional_seconds_precision)]`
>
> where
>
> *day_precision* is the number of digits in the DAY datetime field. Accepted values are 0 to 9. The default is 2.
> ...

So `INTERVAL '182' DAY(3)` defines an interval of 182 days. You need to specify the `(3)` part because the default precision of 2 doesn't allow more than 99 days; without the precision override it will error:

```
select INTERVAL '182' DAY from dual;

ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small
```

but with it you get a valid value:

```
select INTERVAL '182' DAY(3) from dual;

INTERVAL'182'DAY(3)
-------------------
+182 00:00:00
```

And the calculation `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '182' DAY(3)` will give you current time (according to your session time zone, since you're using `current_date` not `sysdate`) 182 days ago. Your query will find rows where `POSTING_DATE` is more recent than 182 days ago.